# Automate setting of User Defined Attributes in IB 3.2

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

Is there a way to automate tasks in Interface Builder version 3.2? Specifically, I need to attache User Defined Attributes to quite a few views.

- can it be done using AppleScript?
- is the XIB format documented well enough to do this using some general purpose scripting language (say Ruby)?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you do not use a UIView subclass where you can define this values?

Comment: I was specifically looking for an alternative to subclassing.